# what kind of SSL certificate required for PWA?

Tags: ssl-certificate, progressive-web-apps

I'm looking to buy SSL certificate for PWA. 
The domain is bought from godday, where I checked a couple of options:

- https://in.godaddy.com/web-security/ssl-certificate?isc=sshl6in01
- https://www.comodo.co.in/ssl-certificates

They have got multiple types of certificates.

Which one is best suited for PWA?
In my case, the app takes the user name and number and saves them in the DB, and it also shows some data from DB to the user.

Comment: It's not 2005 anymore, you don't have to buy a certificate, get one for free from LetsEncrypt: https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/

Comment: [Why are shopping questions bad?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Service workers, as part of PWAs, do not need *special* SSL certificates to work. They simply need a working secure connection (HTTPs).

There are many hosting platforms offering already a SSL certificate out of the box. Of course it depends on your requirements and constrains about hosting providers. However if you are free in the choice of the hosting solution, I would suggest to start with a simple solution. This as general advice, also in line with what Paul suggested in his comment.

Firebase hosting is an example (here [more details](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain) on how to use a custom domain):

[image]

Comment: Let me check if this is available with AWS as well ? As we're planning to use AWS for hosting. What's your recommendation please between AWS vs Firebase ?

Comment: I do not have direct experience with AWS. Firebase is client side oriented and can scale very well. Moreover it offers a generous free tier, that you can use to start/test your app without initial costs. I have a positive experience with Firebase. Both are for sure good and reliable solutions, I would suggest to examine their hosting offers and see what is the best match for you, also considering the future for your app.